# Selecting row with the highest column value among rows with the same value of another column

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

This time, I will ask about something works generally, but when data is huge it fails.

My case is the same in this post.

[how to query for rows that highest column value among rows that have same value for one of the columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459391/how-to-query-for-rows-that-have-highest-column-value-among-rows-that-have-same-va)

I used

```
SELECT `ID`, `PDBID`, `Chain`, `UniProtID`, `PDBASequence`, `pI`, `experiment`, `resolution`
FROM protein p 
WHERE `resolution`= (SELECT MAX(`resolution`)
                              FROM protein 
                              GROUP BY `PDBASequence`
                              HAVING `PDBASequence` = p.`PDBASequence`)
```

I also tried:

```
 SELECT `ID`, `PDBID`, `Chain`, `UniProtID`, `PDBASequence`, `pI`, `experiment`, `resolution`
    FROM protein p 
    WHERE `resolution`= (SELECT MAX(`resolution`)
                                  FROM protein 
                                  WHERE `PDBASequence` = p.`PDBASequence`)
```

I have to group by sequences according to PDBASequence. But, at the same time selected representative must be the one which has the max resolution value.

I tried this code on a small set. Working no problem. However, when I tried to run it on real table which has 80980 rows, execution takes almost forever. In addition, my other computer gives Mysql server has gone away error because of the execution type and pocket size. I fixed the settings in my.ini and ran the code again. Nothing changed. Still no result :(
What should I do?
Thanks 
I assigned index on resolution in protein table. However,it did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

See if this version is any better.

```
SELECT p.`ID`, p.`PDBID`, p.`Chain`, p.`UniProtID`, p.`PDBASequence`, p.`pI`, p.`experiment`, p.`resolution`
FROM protein p 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT PDBASequence, MAX(`resolution`) AS MaxResolution
                    FROM protein 
                    GROUP BY `PDBASequence`) q
        ON p.PDBASequence = q.PDBASequence
            AND p.resolution = q.MaxResolution
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but it gives "#1052 - Column 'PDBASequence' in field list is ambiguous"

Comment: ooops. It should be p.ID etc since I use alias "p" for table protein

Comment: @nenana Correct. I'll modify the answer to reflect that.

Comment: I wrote the first line as p.ID, p.PBDID etc... but still I get the ambiguous error. I look at the code for 10 times and can't see what is wrong with it.

Comment: Execution takes forever still :( what would I do with this code and data :(

Comment: @nenana Do you have an index on PBDASequence?

Comment: It is unique with PDBID and UniProtID. I mean index type is unique. But, I didn't put an index on it. Resolution has index called "ind".

Comment: @nenana: you'd definitely want an index on pbdasequence. It's being used in a corelated subquery and the 'where' executes for every row in the parent query. Doing this on an unindexed field will be (as you're finding out) PAINFULLY slow.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I created another index called inds for PDBASequence. BTW: is it OK to give same index to resolution and pdbasequence. I ask because they are used in the subquery at the same time.